# Cannot import pygame, get error instead

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am attempting to use Pygame for the first time, and did a manual install using `python setup.py install`, but when I try to import it I end up with this message.

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SDL_EnableUNICODE
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
```

Comment: check this https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/47/pygamebase-raises-importerror

Comment: What OS are you using???

Comment: I am using OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: Did you install python or is it the system install of it?

Comment: I installed Python 2.7 myself.

Comment: heya, having the same exact problem, also installed python 2.7 myself. did anyone resolve this issue? thanks.